# Wrap Text; limiting character count per line

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, word-wrap

I am creating a formula or vba to limit per line concatenated information. I'm limited with space "49 characters" to the application in which I need to paste this into.

Is there a formula that I can use to get this information portrayed with little to no manipulation. Possible to not have the words split?

Here is a sample of the formula that I am currently using, with wrapped text:
The cell where this information is complied is "EM"

> =IF(AF1143=0,"NO TOOLING NEEDED/NO PO TO ISSUE",CONCATENATE("Supplier: ",T1143," will build a ",CA1143," tool capable of consistently
>   producing PN ",I1143," per COMPANY & ",E1143," provided released
>   drawing and 3D data to meet 100% of production requirements for the
>   life of the ",G1143," program and service. Tooling Payment Terms: 1/3
>   on Receipt of Tooling PO issuance, 1/3 on Receipt of First Off Parts
>   {First Article Submission} {{To include Full Layout Data and Tooling
>   Data Sheet and 1/3 to Receipt of PPAP Approval from"," ",E1143,",
>   signed PSW will suffice for this confirmation. ","Please keep in
>   contact with COMPANY Buyer with all the above information- as to not
>   delay payment. Due dates above are estimates only. Actual dates are
>   determined by"," ",E1143," ",". ","Weekly Tool Progress Reports (TPR)
>   must be provided to NPC at "," ",E1143,"; these TRP's must be provided
>   as two week intervals. Failure to do so will result in payment delays
>   {Sample of TPR can be viewed from Supplier Portal/SQAM. Critical Event
>   Timing: Please refer to ",E1143," ","NPC Schedule- if NPC Schedule is
>   not available please contact Buyer for copy. Country of Origin: Tool
>   will be produced at: ",BW1143," FOB: ",T1143," ",BW1143, Additional
>   information: PN," ",I1143," ",K1143," ","Tooling Total: ",AF1143,"
>   ","Cost per Tool: ",AR1143," ","Reasoning: ",AS1143," ","Detailed
>   Tooling information: ",AT1143," ","ECI: {if applicable}: ",DW1143,"
>   ","Lead Time: ",EL1143," ","SOP Assumed: ",O1143," ","Mass
>   Production/Life Program {years}: ",Q1143, "Tool Go sent to supplier:
>   ",DG1143," ","Design Review Date: ",DE1143," ",DF1143," ","CER
>   TRACKING NUMBER #: ",FB1143," ","ACCOUNT NUMBER# ",FC1143," ","TOOLING
>   PO#: ",EN1143,"."))

Comment: You could try searching the first 49 characters of the string in reverse for certain characters (space, comma, etc.). Then take the first characters of the string up to this point, append a carriage return and then repeat on the remaining string. This is at least a starting point.

Comment: Understood, and would love to do it this way, but my concatenate'd information can vary in length.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do.  There's no way to fit all that content in 49 characters, so if you had to do it *manually* what would you do?

Comment: No id like for every 49 characters a hard return to the cell to happen to create a wrapped cell with all this information in the cell limited to 49 characters per line.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I meant:

```
Public Function LimitLine (StringToLimit As String, NumberOfLetters As Integer) As String
    Dim TheString As String
    Dim Output As String
    Dim CommaLoc As Integer
    Dim BlankSpaceLoc As Integer

    Output = ""
    TheString = StringToLimit

    Do WHile Len(TheString) > NumberOfLetters
        BlankSpaceLoc = InStrRev(Left(TheString, NumberOfLetters), " ")
        CommaLoc = InStrRev(Left(TheString, NumberOfLetters), ",")
        If BlankSpaceLoc > CommaLoc Then
              Output = Output & Left(TheString, BlankSpaceLoc) & vbCr
              TheString = Right(TheString, Len(TheString) - BlankSpaceLoc)
        Else
              Output = Output & Left(TheString, CommaLoc) & vbCr
              TheString = Right(TheString, Len(TheString) - CommaLoc)
        End If
    Loop
    Output = Output & TheString
    LimitLine = Output
End Function
```